How to automatically handle unknown popups with Selenium?
I'm currently trying to use Selenium in Python to scrape a site with a fixed set of values. I plan to run my code 24/7, but sometimes there are popups, toasts, or other notifications that can appear and cause errors. It would be inconvenient to change the code every time something new comes up.
I use Google Chrome, and I tried these two commands:
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

I thought these would block any kind of popups, but some of them still got through.
We don't know what kind of popups will appear, what their ID or XPATH will be, whether they will be part of a frame, etc.
My question is, how to handle this kind of popups?

--disable-popup-blocking seems like exactly the opposite of what you want.

@TimRoberts Yeah, it does sound confusing. But I checked the documentation: sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/capabilities ,at the "Block pop-up windows" paragraph, and it suggests, chromedriver allows the popups, and you need add this argument to block them again.

--block-new-web-contents will be more strict.  You also have setUnhandledPromptBehaviour for prompts.  (alerts basically)  The other things you are calling popups are just DOM elements and would need to be handled individually.

After some more digging, this is what I found: I changed options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking") to this:
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["disable-popup-blocking"])
The documentations were not clear on this at first, but after some testing, I can confirm that this is the working command.
The other things I wanted to avoid was not really pop-ups as I thought, but 'modals' and 'overlays'. To get rid of them, I got a script, which clones these elements, and replace the originals. Thanks to this, the event listeners will be removed, so they will not activate later.
These two changes did the job for me, only a chat window stayed, but it can be easily closed if it appears.
